# Why is the accuracy of the training set lower than that of the verification set, and this does not seem to be an overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, theory

At the end of the training for picture classification problems, the accuracy of the training set is 10% lower than that of the verification set, and the loss of the training set is 0.2 higher than that of the verification set, and this does not seem to be overfitting. Why?

I used resnet34 for training in the picture binary classification problem. After 150 iterations, the result accuracy of the test set reached more than 90%. However, the accuracy of the training set was lower than that of the verification set, and the loss value was higher.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q :** *"Why?"*

It is quite "enough" to provide less (if any) examples in the verification dataset, that were bad (read failed to get properly) detected in the training dataset.

If there were no misclassification errors in the verification dataset, your detector could easily have earned accuracy of 100%, for which it was quite "enough" to misuse the "selection bias" (a knowingly performed cognitive manipulation) when "composing" a verification dataset.

If in doubt, set the verification dataset have only those cases, that failed at classification in the training dataset (another skewed selection bias case) and your "verification" run ought nosedive into zero accuracy to self-proof the above observations & causal reasoning behind the judgement (if no cause-effect mechanics happen to self-manifest, the predictor has some other, wild, so far undocumented random behaviour—a roulette alike predictor, which could not be a case, if your (biased)-verification dataset, as-was, provided repetitively a systematically better accuracy, as noted above, than the training one—Q.E.D.).

> *I don't understand what you mean clearly. I have repeated the above exercise many times and the result is similar every time—the verification set is better than the training set. Do you mean that the data of my verification set does not contain all features, while the training set contains more samples and features, so the verification set is easier to be predicted?*
>  – LiX [26 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76321020/why-is-the-accuracy-of-the-training-set-lower-than-that-of-the-verification-set/76321137?noredirect=1#comment134586559_76321137)
> *Meanwhile, my data set was divided into training: validation: test =7:2:1. RandomResizedCrop and RandomHorizontalFlip were used in the training set's transforms, and Resize and CenterCrop were used in the verification set's transforms and test set's transforms*
>  – LiX [26 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76321020/why-is-the-accuracy-of-the-training-set-lower-than-that-of-the-verification-set/76321137?noredirect=1#comment134586565_76321137)

**a)**
Repeating was mentioned just as a self-evidence of not having any randomness inside the classifier process. I.e., a same collection of data shall produce a same accuracy in verification batch (validating not the quality of the classifier itself, but the reproducibility of the results).

**b)**
No assumptions on feature manipulations or reduced / extended presence of features was made.

**c)**
 The only point was made—about the accuracy—if one gets into the verification dataset (be it knowingly by "hand-picks" (or a programmed filter to proof / reject this) or just by some kind of "coincidence") only those cases of examples, that were (1) "good" or (2) "bad" in recognitions of the trained classifier, without having about a similar mixture thereof in the "verification" dataset, then the "verification" batch will naturally result in (1) "better-than-in-training" or (2) "worse-than-in-training" accuracy of classifications. There isn't any other magic behind that.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean clearly. I have repeated the above exercise many times and the result is similar every time - the verification set is better than the training set. Do you mean that the data of my verification set does not contain all features, while the training set contains more samples and features, so the verification set is easier to be predicted?

Comment: Meanwhile, my data set was divided into training: validation: test =7:2:1. RandomResizedCrop and RandomHorizontalFlip were used in the training set's transforms, and Resize and CenterCrop were used in the verification set's transforms and test set's transforms

Comment: a) Repeating was mentioned just as a self-evidence of not having any randomness inside the classifier process. I.e. a same collection of data shall produce a same accuracy in verification batch ( validating not the quality of the classifier itself, but the reproducibility of the results ).

Comment: b) No assumptions on feature manipulations or reduced / extended presence of features was made.

Comment: c) The only point was made - about the accuracy - if one gets into the verification dataset ( be it knowingly by "hand-picks" ( or a programmed filter to proof / reject this ) or just by some kind of "coincidence" ) only those cases of examples, that were (1) "good" or (2) "bad" in recognitions of the trained classifier, without having about a similar mixture thereof in the "verification" dataset, then the "verification" batch will naturally result in (1) "better-than-in-training" or (2) "worse-than-in-training" accuracy of classifications. No other magic behind that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It may be that my data augment led to the opposite result and did not make the model better trained. I'll try some other methods.

Comment: You might be aware using any other cause-effect reflective method will face the very same effect, given a skewed selection bias (intentional or not) would get into the verification / test dataset -- shifted (one way or the other) accuracy results will happen again. Proof? Repeat the "manual" pre-selection of "badly" detected samples from training and verification / test batches thereof in the just trained model will nosedive accuracy (as it must do so). On the contrary, pre-select the "best" classified samples and run 'em into verification batch and the very same model gets "improved" accuracy